# doxygen: how to group group members based on entity type

Tags: doxygen

When adding entities to a group, is it possible to have doxygen automatically split the entities up by type? For instance if adding a class to a group I want it to land in a directory called "classes" under the group. If adding a function i want it to land in a Functions directory under the group and for namespaces, defines etc.

Currently what i see is this:

[image: Circle & Rectangle class are added to Group1 as a flat list]

2 classes Circle and Rectangle land in the group as a flat list. If many things are added to a group the view can look quiet messy and so it would be great if there was an easy way of grouping the various things by type. I can imagine how to do it manually, but it feels there might be an easier way.

Desired output,

[image: Desired structure of group]

Comment: What kind of entities you envision? How do you want to group them, please give some examples.

Comment: Thanks for replying albert. Basically instead of the classes Circle & Rectangle being listed directly under the Group1 to which they were added, it would be nice if they were further slit up based on whether they are classes, typedefs, enumerations, functions. So basically i would want Group1 to be structured as in the new image i have added at the end of my original question. If you then further expanded the Classes node i would then want the classes Circle & Rectangle to appear.